# Laravel Eloquent model JOIN a MAX record

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and I'd like to know how to use eloquent model to join a max(date) record...

```
App\SchemasGroup::find(7)->schemas()->get()->max('schemasVersion')->get();
```

I find a group of schemas (schemas_groups table) based on ID, then get the schemas from that group (schemas table), and I want to join the 'date' and 'version' field from schemas_versions table with the last version (so, max date or version field) ...

Relations are defined as:

```
class SchemasGroup extends Model
{
    public function schemas() { return $this->hasMany('App\Schema'); }
}

class Schema extends Model
{
    public function group() { return $this->belongsTo('App\SchemasGroup'); }
    public function versions() { return $this->hasMany('App\SchemasVersion'); }
}

class SchemasVersion extends Model
{
    public function schema() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Schema'); }
    public function updatedBy() { return $this->belongsTo('App\User','updated_by'); }
}
```

Getting the user name who updated that last version would also be lovely...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was easy with defining chaining models.

```
class Schema extends Model
{
   public function group() { return $this->belongsTo('App\SchemasGroup'); }
   public function versions() { return $this->hasMany('App\SchemasVersion'); }
   public function latestVersion() { return $this->hasOne('App\SchemasVersion')->latest(); }
}
```

and then fetching the data with:

```
App\SchemasGroup::with('schemas.latestVersion.updatedBy')->find($schemaGroupId);
```